# Konik Zugferd decimal number

Tags: vb.net, decimal, invoice, zugferd

I try to create a ZUGFeRD invoice using the Koink.io SDK in VB.net.
My code is:

```
myTax.setCalculated(New Amount(New java.math.BigDecimal("833.70"), CurrencyCode.EUR))
```

And in the .xml invoice it is

```
833.7
```

But because of the specification it has to be "833.70" (WITH the zero)
Is it a problem? Can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: is it java or vb now?

Comment: The projekt is in vb.net but the SDK is written in java. I also tried instead of New java.math.BigDecimal("833.70") to use a String "833.70" but there is the same result

Comment: i dont know how vb works but new java objects are normally created with `new` instead of `New`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the stripping of tailing zeros via property files.

```
io.konik.stripTrailingZeros=false
```

See the manual: https://konik.io/docs/index.html#konik_configuration

The new lib version does this automatically, you should upgrade to latest version